# How to wait to read the page in JavaScript in imacros

Tags: imacros

I use a imacros.
However , I do not want to use the code of imacros.
I use a javascript file.
Is an application of the web browser using the imacros.

I want to wait for the reading to imacros.
I wrote the src of the following

```
window.console.log("start");
window.location.href = 'https://google.com/';
function addlisteners(){
 window.alert("read the end");
}
window.onload = addlisteners;
```

[Alert] will not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

window.onload does not work with iMacros. You will need to use SET !WAITPAGECOMPLETE YES to achieve this effect.

[!!WAITPAGECOMPLETE Documentation](http://wiki.imacros.net/!WAITPAGECOMPLETE)

Alternatively, you could use Selenium rather than iMacros which supports muc